# Displaying Time in Correct Format JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

For some reason anytime I try to display time from getting the value from a form on another page the format is weird for example if I 12:58 PM in the time field since I have the inputType as time when I submit and look at the time it displays as Time: 12%3A58 select and I do not know how to fix it I try doing some research but didn't understand some of those things

```
Javascript to assign time to the field
var time = document.forms["myForm"]["time"].value;

The time field
<div>
           <label for="myTime">Time:</label>
           <input type="time"  name="time" value="hh:mm:ss.ms" />
           <p id="time"></p>
        </div><br>  

Code to display
var time = getQueryVariable("time");
    details = details + "Time:  "+time+"<br>";
```

Comment: Did you know that `%3A` is the URL percent encoding of the colon `:` ?

Comment: About how to fix it: `var time = decodeURIComponent(getQueryVariable("time"))`

Comment: Thank You @E.Sundin for the help I got it to display but is there a way to also display either am or pm after the time?